# RedHat single command to add user to sudoers

Tags: linux

I am trying to automate the build of my redhat server.

> To add an existing user to sudoer:
>
> Add user to sudoers file by using sudo visudo and add the following
>   line:
>
> `USERNAME  ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL`

How do I perform above task using RedHat commands?

Answer (score 3):

One way would be just to add `username ALL = NOPASSWD:ALL` to the end of `/etc/sudoers`.

```
echo "username ALL = NOPASSWD:ALL" >> /etc/sudoers
```